# Can we push data into firebase real time database using url query string?

Tags: firebase

i want push some data to my real time database firebase, I have my database structure like this
[image]

I've successfully done inserting data using query string with PHP using $_GET method in free web hosting, but it has limited hit request and i don't want to pay for web hosting, since I know firebase is free, I would like to use it.

ok so, i want to push the data using url query string. when i hit the url like 
https://gps-iot-8a30e.firebaseio.com/koordinat?created_at=2020-01-01&latitude=6.231435&longitude=6.231454
the data should be added to 'koordinat' reference and automatically generate the key id. is there any way to insert data like that? What should i do? should I make some sort of REST API server? any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to add data to the Firebase Realtime Database REST API with a GET request. The new data will always have to be in the body of the request, which `GET` requests don't support.

See the Firebase documentation on [ways to save data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-ways-to-save) with the REST API.

What you *can* do is create a custom endpoint on for example Cloud Functions that takes the request you send from your PHP, and then converts that into a format that the Realtime Database supports. If you're doing this on Cloud Functions, you might as well use the Node.js SDK that Firebase provides, instead of dealing with the REST API there.